# Flask dynamic import pattern

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask application with a directory structure like so (simplified for question).

```
app.py
/some-serivce
  - __init__.py
  - impl1.py
  - impl2.py
  - impl3.py
```

Based on the configuration, I want to import and instantiate one of the implementations for `some-service`. I currently do something that seems somewhat hacky. In my `app.py` I create `app.config` from a python module containing a string referencing the desired implementation.

```py
import importlib

...

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(config.dev)


mod = importlib.import_module(f"services.{app.config['SERVICE_IMPL']}")
mod.service_init(app)
```

And in the implementation I have a `service_init` function that looks something like this:

```py
def service_init(app):
   app.config['SERVICE_INSTANCE'] = ServiceImpl1()
```

What feels hacky to me is storing an instance of the desired service implementation on the app config. However, I haven't seen anything that points to how to implement the desired behavior in the docs.

How can I dynamically configure a service class that can be one of many implementations? And how can I access it in some way other than storing it in the `app.config`?